# Proper way to stop a TensorFlow Dataset `from_generator`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to use a TensorFlow Dataset built with `from_generator` to access a formatted file. Most everything works except I don't know how to stop the Dataset iterator when the generator runs out of data (the generator just returns empty lists forever when you go out of range).

My actual code is very complex, but I can mock up the situation with this short program:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_batch_generator_fn(batch_size=10, dset_size=100):
    feats, targs = range(dset_size), range(1, dset_size + 1)

    def batch_generator_fn():
        start_idx, stop_idx = 0, batch_size
        while True:
            # if stop_idx > dset_size: --- stop action?
            yield feats[start_idx: stop_idx], targs[start_idx: stop_idx]
            start_idx, stop_idx = start_idx + batch_size, stop_idx + batch_size

    return batch_generator_fn

def test(batch_size=10):
    dgen = make_batch_generator_fn(batch_size)
    features_shape, targets_shape = [None], [None]
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        dgen, (tf.int32, tf.int32),
        (tf.TensorShape(features_shape), tf.TensorShape(targets_shape))
    )
    feats, targs = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        counter = 0
        try:
            while True:
                f, t = sess.run([feats, targs])
                print(f, t)
                counter += 1
                if counter > 15:
                    break
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('end of dataset at counter = {}'.format(counter))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

If I know the number of records in advance, I can tune the number of batches, but I don't always know. I've tried putting some code in the snippet above where I have a comment line like `stop action?`. In particular, I've tried raising an `IndexError`, but TensorFlow doesn't like this, even if I explicitly `catch` it in my execution code. I also tried raising a `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`, but I'm not sure how to instantiate it: the constructor requires three arguments - 'node_def', 'op', and 'message', and I'm not quite sure what to use for 'node_def' and 'op' in general.

I'd appreciate any thoughts or comments on this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return when you meet your stop criteria:

```
def make_batch_generator_fn(batch_size=10, dset_size=100):
    feats, targs = range(dset_size), range(1, dset_size + 1)

    def batch_generator_fn():
        start_idx, stop_idx = 0, batch_size
        while True:
            if stop_idx > dset_size:
                return
            else:
                yield feats[start_idx: stop_idx], targs[start_idx: stop_idx]
                start_idx, stop_idx = start_idx + batch_size, stop_idx + batch_size

    return batch_generator_fn
```

This is in line with the behavior specified in the [Python 3 documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

> In a generator function, the return statement indicates that the generator is done and will cause StopIteration to be raised. The returned value (if any) is used as an argument to construct StopIteration and becomes the StopIteration.value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It works with following lines:

```
dataset_size = your dataset size
batch_size = your batch size
dataset = your tf.data.Dataset
steps_per_epoch = dataset_size // batch_size

for data, _ in zip(dataset, range(steps_per_epoch)):
    # your train_step
```

The iteration will stop when it's through.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 hi, I've updated my code, I think it explains itself :)